# Getting a list of checked boxes in Kendo UI Web TreeView

Tags: telerik, treeview, kendo-ui

How might one get a list of checked checkboxes in a Kendo UI Web TreeView?
I can't find this functionality anywhere in the API but I would think this would be a pretty basic operation..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is actually no API method but you can get them easily with jQuery.

To get the checkbox selected inputs use

```
$('#treeviewName :checked');
```

To get the checked container **li** elements use:

```
$('#treeviewName :checked').closest('li');
```

Once you have the **li** element you can pass it to the [dataItem](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/treeview#dataitem) method of the TreeView and get the underlying model and thus its ID or other properties.

Comment: This solution doesn't account for scenarios where you check children and you have yet to expand the parent node because the li and checkboxes haven't been added yet via javascript. I am looking into a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

On Kendo demos they provide the following algorithm:

```
    // function that gathers IDs of checked nodes
    function checkedNodeIds(nodes, checkedNodes) {
        for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
            if (nodes[i].checked) {
                checkedNodes.push(nodes[i].id);
            }

            if (nodes[i].hasChildren) {
                checkedNodeIds(nodes[i].children.view(), checkedNodes);
            }
        }
    }

    // show checked node IDs on datasource change
    function onCheck() {
        var checkedNodes = [],
            treeView = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView"),
            message;

        checkedNodeIds(treeView.dataSource.view(), checkedNodes);

        if (checkedNodes.length > 0) {
            message = "IDs of checked nodes: " + checkedNodes.join(",");
        } else {
            message = "No nodes checked.";
        }

        $("#result").html(message);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Gathering the checked nodes from a treeview](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/web/treeview/overview):

```
var treeview = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView");
var checkedNodes = [];

function gatherStates(nodes) {
    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        if (nodes[i].checked) {
            checkedNodes.push(nodes[i].id);
        }

        if (nodes[i].hasChildren) {
           gatherStates(nodes[i].children.view());
        }
    }
}

gatherStates(treeview.dataSource.view());
```

This doesn't seem to account for unexpanded nodes that are checked by cascading: the checkChildren property.